# Getting exact user input, c

Tags: c, string, char

I've been looking for a solution to this and haven't found any, I've been trying to make a string that is the size that the user inputs, is there any way to go about doing this? (I'm trying to eliminate null values in the char array).

Edit: I apologize about the missing info, the compiler is gcc -std=c99, and the OS is Ubuntu.

here is the part of the main program that I'm focusing on + the headers (not entirely completed), I'm trying to create a string that is the same length as the user inputs, and that contains the same values.

The compiler currently doesn't recognize myalloc and getline

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
  char *string;
  int selection, bytes_read, nbytes = 255;
  unsigned char key, letter;

  do {
    ...
    printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
    string = (char *) myalloc(nbytes + 1);
    bytes_read = getline(&string, &nbytes, stdin);
    ...
  }while(..);
}
```

Comment: http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html

Comment: `getline` is probably the answer, but I feel that your question is unclear. What do you call the size of the user input? What about getting input from a pipe?

Comment: I think getline is defined in POSIX. Which OS/Compiler are you using?

Comment: Do you mean that if the user inputs `42` then you want a string of length 42 and none of the characters should be `NUL`?  (Except, hopefully, the 42nd.  You'll need `scanf`, `malloc` and `memset`.)  Or do you want a string of length 2 that reads `"42"`?  (You'll need `getline` and maybe overwrite the trailing `\n` with `\0`.)

Comment: @5gon12eder I was talking about a string of length 2 that reads "42", the bigger problem is I have to use the gcc compiler and idk if getline works with that.

Comment: @AbdullahLeghari I'm using the gcc compiler

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yeah sorry, I was talking about the length of the string that the user is inputing

Comment: `getline` works with GCC.  If you have any actual code you are struggling with, please show it to us.

Comment: @user3308353: please edit your question to improve it. Show some code, tell which compiler and operating system are you using.

Comment: @5gon12eder well, I posted the code, the problem is, that I'm limited to the libraries that I have with c, and the library that has getline in it is not one of them.

Comment: Add `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` *before* `#include`ing `stdio.h`.  See [`getline(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

Comment: And for `myalloc`: This is a typo.  The standard library function is called `malloc`.  See [`malloc(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html).

Comment: @5gon12eder thanks for the help so far, but now the getline isn't even waiting for user input, it literally automatically takes in a blank string, any ideas?

Comment: @5gon12eder 
do {
  ...
  if(selection == 1) {
    printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
    string = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
    bytes_read = getline(&string, &nbytes, stdin);
    if(bytes_read == -1) {
      printf("ERROR!\n);
    }
    else {
      printf("%s, string);
      printf("Enter a key:\n);
      scanf("%c", &key);
      for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(string); i++) {
        printf("%d ", encode(string[i], key, i));
      }
    }
  }
  selection = -1; /*to terminate the program*/
}while (selection > 0);

Comment: I have posted a minimal working example as an answer.  Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the following as **`main.c`**:

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main()
{
  size_t n = 0;
  char * line = NULL;
  ssize_t count;
  printf("Enter a sentence: ");
  count = getline(&line, &n, stdin);
  if (count < 0)
    {
      perror("getline");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  /* If it bothers you: get rid of the terminating '\n', if any. */
  if (line[count - 1] == '\n')
    line[count - 1] = '\0';
  printf("Your input was: '%s'\n", line);
  free(line);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Then, in a terminal:

```
$ gcc -o main main.c
$ ./main
Enter a sentence: the banana is yellow
Your input was: 'the banana is yellow'
```

There is also a more extensive example of using `getline` included in its [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).